# Does the score output of a classification model has a global meaning?

Tags: classification, object-detection, softmax

The scores-output layer contains the class scores that the model generated for the current sample and it is passed thru the softmax layer to get the final output in the form of a probabilities vector.

My question is whether these scores have any global meaning, when compared with scores of other samples from the dataset?

> The way I see it, a standard classification model is trained on the
>   output of the softmax layer, so the model only "cares" about the
>   relative scores within each sample. So it has no mechanism for
>   decreasing the global scores of a sample - a scores vector of
>   [101,102,103] gets the same treatment as [1,2,3]. Am I correct in my
>   understanding?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the final layer, before softmax activation, is the log odds of the classes. Softmax isn't a linear function, so [10,20,30] going into softmax won't give the same answer as [1,2,3].

Comment: My mistake, I have edited the question to my initial intent.

Comment: Ah yes, if the values are shifted rather than multiplied by a constant, the result is the same, because they're really values in the log domain. But I think the answer stands about the interpretation of the values themselves, which do have an absolute meaning (up to a constant)